# JS - Display div every 5 seconds with fade effect and close button

Tags: javascript

I have now looked for a solution on many other forums, but I can't find the right one, maybe someone here can help me :)

I have coded an notification popup on the left bottom of my site like:

[image: Image Link]

I want now display my `div` class (notification popup) every 5 seconds with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` effect and show it for 5 seconds, then the same again without stopping.

**My Js Code:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("show-div");

var myIntv = setInterval(function() {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}, 5 * 1000);
```

But it display my `div` just after 5 seconds and dont repeat it. Any one an Idea how can i do this?

**My Second Question**

I have also an little close `span` class in my popup window.

How can I stop the notification popup from appearing every second (If the first code works) and make the `div` class `display:none;` for the users current Session, if he clicked the close button?

I have tried it with:

```
$('#close-div').click(function() {
    clearInterval(myIntv);
});
```

But dont work.

Works with JS or must i use `PHP Session`?

Comment: "it display my div just after 5 seconds and dont repeat it"...actually the code will repeat, but the problem is it only _shows_ the div, never hides it, which means it looks like nothing else is happening. So you need to check if it's shown currently, and then write some more code to hide it, if so.

Comment: P.S. Please don't ask multiple separate questions within the same post, it puts your question in danger of being closed due to lack of focus. Deal with one issue at a time. If you have a different issue, post a separate question about it.

Comment: you're better off using a CSS animation

Comment: P.P.S regarding the second issue, we can't know how it "dont work" because we have no idea if you're getting script errors, or if you've got jQuery in your page, or if you've correctly identified the HTML elements (since we can't see any HTML), or whether you're just complaining that it doesn't persist between page refreshes. It's unclear specifically what the issue is, and ther eis not enough info there to assist you. But yes you do need to persist the value between reloads, and you could either use PHP session, or maybe localstorage or something like that, depending on exact requirements

Comment: Yes its show currently, i have hide the `div` class with `display:none;` and after 5 seconds it pop up. No errors, i just want add an fideIn and fadeOut effect and hide the div class after 5 seconds again and display it again after 5 seconds forever.

Comment: can you give the full code?

Comment: Full code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Question :
    var div = document.getElementById("show-div");

```
var showFlag = true;
var myIntv = setInterval(function() {
    if(showFlag){
        div.style.display = 'block'; 
        showFlag = false;
    }
    else{
        div.style.display = 'none';
        showFlag = true;   
   }

}, 5 * 1000);
```

Second Question: Clear Interval should work.

```
$('#close-div').click(function() {
    clearInterval(myIntv);
});
```

Comment: Yes looks nice thanks, and how can i add the the Fade effect? Is `clearInterval` the correct solution to close the popup for this user session and dont display it again for it? Its just stop the 5 seconds loop

Comment: if my answer looks nice, I don't know why it is down voted.
1. if you want to achieve fade-In effect, there are various methods:
    a) use css animation.
    b) use jquery slideToggle() 
     reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slidetoggle 
2) clearInterval just stops the setInterval effect. Please share the code to which you have written to show popup.

Comment: I have edited my comment. Please use animation or slideToggle :-). if you share the popup code, I could help you out. Thank you. Hala, Happy coding :-)

Comment: Oh thanks, css animation is the right one for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementById("show-div");

var isShown = false; 
var myIntv = setInterval(function() {
    if(isShown){
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    isShown = !isShown;
 }, 5 * 1000);
```